# how to sort a string array based on elements of another List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a string array - lets imagine something like;

`string[] Array = {a,b,c,d,e,a,b,c,d,e,a,b,c,d,e}`

and I've a List - something like;

`List<string> l = {a,b,c,d,e}`

I need to sort Array like:

`string[] sortedArray = {a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d,e,e,e}`

My working is:

```
public static List<string> SortByList(List<string> values, List<string> order)
        {
            return values.OrderBy(x => order.IndexOf(x)).ToList();
        }
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> alpha = new List<string>();
            List<string> m = new List<string>();
            string[] gamma = null;

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(pathSave))
            {    
                foreach (string st in parts)
                {
                        alpha.Add(st);
                }
            }
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathSave, true))
        {
            gamma = File.ReadAllLines(pathSave);
            foreach (string i in gamma)
            {
                l.Add(i);
            }
            m = SortByList(l, alpha);
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathSave))
        {
            sw.Write("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
            foreach (string st in m)
            {
                sw.Write(st);
                sw.Write("\r\n");
            }
        }
        }
```

In short, `alpha` is a list of string elements and `lines` is a string Array. I want to sort `lines` with respect of elements in `alpha`. Can someone please guide. Thanks

Comment: `array1.Orderby(x => array2.IndexOf(x))`.

Comment: Not sure that the question is correct. It's more likely, your GUI thread timeout and you have to deport your treatment in another one.

Comment: @romain-aga this part of code is wrong = `foreach (string a in alpha.ToList())
            {
                var lines1 = lines.OrderBy(x => a).ToList();
                beta.Add(lines1);
            }`

Comment: @juharr `array1.Orderby(x => array2.IndexOf(x))` has removed the error but isn't changing anything in array1.

Comment: @RehanKhan That doesn't change `array1` it returns an sequence of the items in `array1` in the order you wanted.  You can then iterate over that to do whatever you want with it or use `ToArray` and assign it back to `array1` if you want.

Comment: @juharr no it isn't even giving the sequence i want - it is giving me Array1 as it is. No OrderBy function performed. Can you show me in the code?

Comment: @juharr sorry, there is no such thing as array2 in my question. my mistake. I was mistaking a list with array2. I have edited my question. please have a review.

Comment: While trying to find a solution, I realized that I got exactly the same as @juharr in his first comment: `List<string> lines1 = lines.OrderBy(x => alpha.IndexOf(x)).ToList();`. It works. (Note: you don't need to put that in a for loop on the alpha list)

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for the response but `lines1` is not a List. Its an Array. Can you please fix that in your code?

Comment: There you go: `string[] lines1 = lines.OrderBy(x => alpha.IndexOf(x)).ToArray();`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, and like I told @juharr, `string[] lines1 = lines.OrderBy(x => alpha.IndexOf(x)).ToArray();` isn't making any difference. Here is image of the array(gamma) [Before](http://postimg.org/image/5kw3u1p8h/) OrderBy and [After](http://postimg.org/image/dwbbhtou9/) OrderBy.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I have also edit and updated my question.

Comment: What's with the `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader`? You don't even use them in your code. And `RemoveAll` and `Regex`? Are those really part of the underlying problem? You stated a very good and clear problem: "how to sort a string array based on elements of List". You showed an example of how the content of the `array` and the `list` might look like and showed what the content of the expected `sortedArray` should look like. And you got an answer that solves that problem: `string[] sortedArray = array.OrderBy(list.IndexOf).ToArray();`. This works. So maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Btw. in your `Before` and `After` screenshots, the breakpoint (yellow marker) both times is at the end of the method. Of course then you get the exact same display for `gamma` wether you hover over it in the first line or the second. You cannot go back in time just by moving the mouse up or down.

Comment: @Corak, I've edited my question and removed breakpoint and ran code given above. Output file is exactly same as the input file without any change (OrderBy in this case).

Comment: @RehanKhan - what I'm trying to get at, is that you're doing too much at once. You know now how to sort the content of one list/array by the contents of another list/array. Take @Jonathans answer. Now don't specify `values` in code, but read it from a file. Only make this rather small change. Now if you get that to work, try writing the `sortedList` to a (different) file. You should be able to repeat the tests as many times as you like. Take one input file, order it, and write (override) a different file. And up to now, `order` didn't change. Now change how you get `order`.

Comment: You haven't shown us what `parts` is, so maybe there is already the problem, or in how you get your `alpha` or whatever. The point is, start with a solution where you know it works. Change it little step by little step. And after each step, make sure it still does exactly what you expect it to do. Proceed until it solves your problem. *Don't* start with an already messed up "solution" trying to force it to do what you want; like what you're doing right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var values = new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e"};
        var order = new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"};

        var sortedList = SortByList(values, order);

        foreach(var i in sortedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    public static List<string> SortByList(List<string> values, List<string> order){
        return values.OrderBy(x => order.IndexOf(x)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Output: aaabbbcccdddeee

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is correct in its literal context but as I'm implementing its concept in my code, unfortunately its not giving the desired output. I've edited my code according to your answer shown in above question. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: I guess I'm not entirelyl sure what you're trying to do here. I thought you were trying to sort, but clearly there's more to your spec. Are you trying to: open a file, read it's contents, sort the contents, and then append the sorted content back into the file (not overwrite the existing content?). I think @Corak's comment above is correct. Breaking down your code into multiple methods, and asking questions at a more granular level would be better.